# Wait for XmlListModel if not reloaded successfull

Tags: javascript, qml

I must reload some XmlListModel, but it takes many seconds. I don't know how. I use analyze in Qt Creator, and most of the time it takes refreshTableListModelsReady and onrefreshTableListModelReady. Anyone had a better solution ?

```
property bool refreshTableListModelsReady: crmListModel.status == XmlListModel.Ready && allSMSPremiumReceived.status == XmlListModel.Ready

    function refreshTableList()
    {
        showMessage("Refreshing...","2");
        allSMSPremiumReceived.reload(); // reload XML list
        crmListModel.reload(); //reload xml crm list
    }

    onRefreshTableListModelsReadyChanged:
    {
        if(allSMSPremiumReceived.count!=0 && crmListModel.count!=0) //if xmllistmodel is clean
        {
            if(refreshTableListModelsReady==true) // if bool is true
            {
                fillListTableNumberModel(); //copy two xmllistmodel to one ListModel
                cutNumbersAndSortModel(); // sort and cuts some data in ListModel
                sortByTime();             // sort data by time in ListModel
                showMessage("Refreshed","0");
            }
        }
    }
```